# How to check if client is connected before writing message to stream?

Tags: c#, networking

I want to check if a client is connected and the stream is open before the server writes a message to the stream.

```
if (client.Connected == true)
{
   stream.Write(sendBuffer, 0, sendBuffer.Length);
}
```

I tried the code above, but when I try to send many messages in a short time, the server hits the if condition and the client is still connected, but in the loop the client isn't connected anymore and the server crashes. How to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can't, you have to try..catch the code and set something like "packet write error" as result of the operation.